# Final Fantasy 7 missing content/trophies

Tags: achievements, ps4, final-fantasy-7

I bought Final Fantasy VII for the PS4 (the version with trophies), and I'm going for the platinum in this game...

I did some research and I noticed that are some **missable trophies**. I don't want to replay the game entirely just because of some trophies but at the same time I want this game to be a new experience and don't want to spoil the game following a complete walktrough...

Currently I am in the final of part/disc 1, where you need to head to the Temple of Acients and I've **done** those missable **trophies**:

- [(Bronze) Consummate Cross-dresser](http://psnprofiles.com/trophy/4126-FINAL-FANTASY-VII/4-Consummate-Cross-dresser)
- [(Bronze) Best Bromance](http://psnprofiles.com/trophy/4126-FINAL-FANTASY-VII/7-Best-Bromance)
- [(Bronze) Won't You be My Valentine?](http://psnprofiles.com/trophy/4126-FINAL-FANTASY-VII/11-Wont-You-be-My-Valentine)
- [(Silver) See the Light](http://psnprofiles.com/trophy/4126-FINAL-FANTASY-VII/21-See-the-Light)

My questions are:

- Is there something else missable?
- Should I be worried about the rest of the trophies?
- Or can I play the game my way and grind the rest of the trophies post game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the link you provided, you can get a list of all Missable trophies:

[image]

Just click on them and read what you need to do so you don't miss them.